# remove not working with live function jQuery

Tags: jquery, live

I want ot remove a table which is created on run time after page load . I used live function to remove respective table but its not working please help me guys you **[can check fiddle here](http://jsfiddle.net/2JG9w/)** or check my code below.

**SCRIPT**

```
var countTR = 0;
$('.addMore').click(function(e){
    e.preventDefault();
    countTR++
    if(countTR<=4)
    {
    $(this).siblings('div').append('<table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0"><tr><td width="50%"><p>Name </p><input type="text" name="2" id="2"></td><td width="" ><p>Mobile No. </p><input type="text" name=" " id=" "></td></tr><tr><td width="50%"><p>Email ID </p><input type="text" name="2" id="2"></td><td width="" ><p>GV Denomination </p><select name=" 7" ><option>IVR</option><option>SMS</option><option>Email</option></select></td></tr><tr><td width="50%"><p>&nbsp;</p></td><td width="" align="right" ><p><a href="#" class="removeTr">Remove</a></p></td></tr></table>')
    }
    else{alert('Sorry you cant add more')}

    })

    $('.removeTr').live('click',function(){

        alert('clear')
        $(this).parent().parent('table').remove();
    countTR--;
        })
```

**HTML**

```
<div class="addManually othersTable">
                <table width="100%" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%"><p>Name </p>
                      <input type="text" name=" 2" id=" 2"></td>
                    <td width="" ><p>Mobile No. </p>
                      <input type="text" name=" " id=" "></td>
                  </tr>
                  <tr>
                    <td width="50%"><p>Email ID </p>
                      <input type="text" name=" 2" id=" 2"></td>
                    <td width="" ><p>GV Denomination </p>
                      <select name=" 7" >
                        <option>IVR</option>
                        <option>SMS</option>
                        <option>Email</option>
                      </select></td>
                  </tr>
                </table>

              </div><a href="#" class="link addMore spacingTop">Add more</a>
```

Comment: Couldn't you open your console: `Object [object Object] has no method 'live'` ???

Comment: live is deprecated and removed, the favorite methods is now `.on()`.

Answer (score 1):

You need [event delegation](https://learn.jquery.com/events/event-delegation/), also use [`closest`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/) to get the parent table instead of using parent() multiple times

**[Live Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/rajaadil/2JG9w/2/)**

```
$(document).on('click', '.removeTr', function () {
    alert('clear')
    $(this).closest('table').remove();
    countTR--;
});
```

> Delegated events have the advantage that they can process events from
>   descendant elements that are added to the document at a later time. By
>   picking an element that is guaranteed to be present at the time the
>   delegated event handler is attached, you can use delegated events to
>   avoid the need to frequently attach and remove event handlers, [MSDN](https://api.jquery.com/on/).

Answer (score 1):

Use event delegation and use [`.closest()`](http://api.jquery.com/closest/)

```
$(this).closest('table').remove();
```

---

```
$(document.body).on('click','.removeTr',function(){    
    $(this).closest('table').remove();
});
```

You're using jQuery version 1.10, `.live()` is no more exists in it, you have to use `.on()`

[**Fiddle**](http://jsfiddle.net/2JG9w/3/)

Answer (score 0):

Try this will work : [See fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/ankittyagi/2JG9w/1/)

[.live](http://api.jquery.com/live/) is depriciated you must use [.on](http://jqapi.com/#p=on) Or [.on](http://learn.jquery.com/events/event-basics/)

```
$(document).on('click','.removeTr',function(){    
    $(this).closest('table').remove();
    countTR--;
})
```